# Accessing Arrays From Object

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, axios

I feel like this is a basic question but everything I try is not working. I am trying to access Arrays that are nested inside object.

When do `console.log(response.data)` I will get a Object with Arrays inside

```
{
  scanned: [],
  complete: [],
  received: [],
  review: [],
}
```

But if i then try to access one of the arrays with `console.log(response.data.scanned)` I will get `undefined`

My question is how do I access Arrays nested in Object? is this even possible?

*Update
Here is the response I get with just `console.log(response)`
[image]

Here is the response for `console.log(response.data)`
[image]

Now if I try `console.log(response.data['scanned'])` it will still give me undefined

If I try `console.log(response['data.scanned'])` or `console.log(response['data']['scanned'])` will alse give me undefined

Comment: `console.log(response.data.scanned)` must work. If it doesn't, then the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: could you provide the code that wraps the given snippet?

Comment: Please view the Update section to my post. Thanks! @MatusDubrava

Comment: console.log(response.data.Scanned). Capital S

Comment: it looks like the key is capitalized - oh @TyKroll got it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

console.log(response.data.Scanned). Capital S

Comment: I had tried that before too, but it seems to be working now. Thank you for the help!